# K&R 1.6 Array example not printing

Tags: c

I recently bought The C programming language and have been going through the text slowly making sure I understand everything. I came across this array example (chapter 1.6), which I do understand fully thanks to many of questions already being answered on Stack Overflow.

The issue is when I run the program, nothing prints out. This book has a habit of making feel unintelligent at times so I apologize in advance if this is a noobie question. I assure you I searched for an answer for quite sometime.

This is the code from the text. I'm using XCode 4:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count digits, white space, others */
main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];
    nwhite = nother = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;

    printf("digits =");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);

    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

Why does it not run??

Comment: Oof, you should also understand why K&R used the _indenting_ style they did. This code is illegible...

Comment: Wow .. ***no*** indentation at all, or blank lines .. really really hard to read ... you may want to make it easier for people wanting to help.

Comment: Why comparing `int` against `char` ( `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`)? Though, it doesn't hurt in this case.

Comment: @ouah `c` is of int type while the `'0'` is of char type.

Comment: @Mahesh no, `'0'` is of type `int`.

Comment: I apologize for the improper formatting, I quickly grabbed the first code I saw in another question that was formatted this way.

Comment: When run from the command line (on a Mac, but not from XCode), the code you supply works.  When run on its source code as provided by you, it yields: `digits = 9 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1, white space = 90, other = 345` for 448 characters total, which is the size given by `ls` for the source file.  Thus, there is something up with the way you're running it; it needs a file to read as standard input, for example.

Comment: @ouah http://ideone.com/Yyk7F

Comment: @Mahesh `char` in C++, but we are talking C here (and it is `int` in C).

Comment: @ouah Oops... Sorry for the noise. Just curious, why the distinction ?

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

ensures that your `while` loop continues until `getchar()` reads the character required to cause the condition to be false. So until you input to the terminal the `EOF` character, it will carry on - in order to do this you need to use the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: @GCornish: how were you ending the input?

Comment: It would work but you would need to type CTRL-D to terminate the while loop

Comment: Oh ok, I got the "aha" moment now. Again thank you for your help. I'll make sure to format next time.

Comment: @mathematician1975 - While you seem to have hit the nail on the head, I think it would be much better to just explain what EOF means, and how to produce one from the keyboard. The *change EOF to `Q`* bit is shaky and might confuse future visitors, esp. those new to C. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: @ArjunShankar - fair point. ill correct this. was just trying to illustrate what was going on in simple terms

Answer (score 3):

I didn't spot any discrepancies between your version and the book's version -- I think the problem is probably in how you are *running* the program.

`getchar()` reads a character from *standard input*. That can be a terminal device, a pipe to another program, or even a network socket (rare).

When you run this program, it probably just sits there until you type some characters *and then terminate the input* -- which most terminals will do if you type a Control+D character on a new line.

Easier is to give the program some input via an easily reproducible mechanism -- either piping in a file or contents via `echo`:

```
./a.out < /etc/passwd
echo "hello world" | ./a.out
```

You could use any program in place of `echo` -- you could also use `ls(1)`:

```
ls | ./a.out
```

Sadly, the K&R book is excellent at many things but it mostly ignores the development and execution environment -- C is intended for such a huge array of machines that the specification does not include a hierarchical directory structure, to pick one easy example.